# Static Class Problem multi project

Tags: c#, class

I have two applications and 1 class for database process.
First Application is a Windows forms application like

```
public class Form1 :System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
  public Form1()
  {
  }
}
```

And my second application is a Windows control library application like

```
public class MyControl :System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
{
  public MyControl()
  {
  //
  //Some Code
  //
  }
}
```

and my class is static class like

```
public static class Deneme
{
  public static void Connect()
  {
  //
  //SomeCode
  //
  }

  public static void CreateTable(string SqlCommandP)
  {
  //
  //Some Code
  //
  }
}
```

I compile the control library application and get a `.dll` file. After that, I'm adding this file to Windows application project toolbox. I can use this control.

My problem is that:
I am using `static class` in a Windows application and control library application maybe I will make another control libary application.
How can I use this `static class` from one project it have to be one in a project?

Comment: What are you asking? I can't even understand this question.

Comment: Are you asking how to share your static class with two separate projects?

Comment: Using static methods for data access is not advisable.

Comment: @James: in what way do you mean? Obviously, the OP has some *'connect'* intent ...not sure what it is, though. I would pass a connection string or connection object to the `Connect()` method if I were to use a static class like this ...

Answer (score 3):

If the static class `Deneme` is to be shared between the 2 applications, you should place that static object in it's own library which both the WinForm project and the control project will reference.

Answer (score 1):

Reference one project to the other? It seems like you're forgetting the Project Reference somewhere. Being more specific with the question might be helpful, though.